# why can't I interact with GitHub using SSH

Tags: git, github, ssh

When I try to clone my project from GitHub using ssh.

```
git clone git@github.com:{myname}/{myproject}.git
```

The terminal prompts me to enter

```
git@github.com's password:
```

Before this, I have generated the public key and put it in the GitHub account.

My command is

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$my_email"
```

And I don't know why I should enter a password when using git clone, I tried my Github account and Linux account. But it didn't work. What am I missing here?

---

When run `ssh -Tv git@github.com`
I got

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [$my_linux_WAN_ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:V2mCp8e57TQ9rLfhLv+ATIDG/l0c3z0Ynr2T/r7zdks
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/deeplearn/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:EwlVGDfp7GYd+LT8l+dconPRVKhfwSbzkX2CRu+xIZA /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@github.com's password:
```

Comment: What is the output of `ssh -Tv git@github.com` ? Please copy/paste text and format it as code to make it readable.

Comment: Did you add the private key (with `ssh-add`) before trying to use git against the repo? And welcome to SO!

Comment: `debug1: identity file /home/deeplearn/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory` indicates that you didn't actually store the key on the system. That's OK *if* you're using ssh-agent to store the key somewhere else and deliver it to programs that ask for it...

Comment: "debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password" Github's ssh servers don't offer to do password authentication. The remote software version is also wrong for github's servers. You're not actually communicating with github. According to the "Connecting to github.com..." line, you're actually connecting to one of your local systems...?

Answer (score 1):

Something about your system or network is misconfigured.  The IP address for `github.com` should not be your Linux WAN port IP, GitHub does not use OpenSSH for its SSH access, and GitHub does not at the moment offer an ECDSA host key, so all of those are indications that you're not connecting to the server you think you are.

It's possible that your `/etc/hosts` file contains an entry for github.com, or it's possible that your network gateway is misconfigured to intercept all SSH traffic.  You should investigate that more thoroughly and then verify that the host key matches the RSA `ssh_key_fingerprints` entry at https://api.github.com/meta.  This is one of the reasons it's important to verify SSH host keys before connecting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I check my `/etc/hosts` and find the wrong entry for github.com :)

Comment: Hah, I skipped right over the elided IP address text. If I had noticed it I would have asked why he put `$my_linux_WAN_ip` there instead of the github public IP...